# Lua read beginning of a string

Tags: string, lua

I am making an adventure game and I'm trying to make the user input a string and if the string starts with action then it will read the rest of the line in a function.

```
act=io.read();
if act=="blah" then doSomething();
elseif act=="action"+random string then readRestOfStringAndDoSomethinWwithIt();
else io.write("Unknown action\n");
end
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have a look at this page http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringRecipes:

```
function string.starts(String,Start)
   return string.sub(String,1,string.len(Start))==Start
end
```

Then use

```
elseif string.starts(act, "action") then ...
```

Answer (score 22):

Use `string.find` with the `^` which anchors the pattern at beginning of string:

```
ss1 = "hello"
ss2 = "does not start with hello"
ss3 = "does not even contain hello"

pattern = "^hello"

print(ss1:find(pattern ) ~= nil)  -- true:  correct
print(ss2:find(pattern ) ~= nil)  -- false: correct
print(ss3:find(pattern ) ~= nil)  -- false: correct
```

You can even make it a method for all strings:

```
string.startswith = function(self, str) 
    return self:find('^' .. str) ~= nil
end

print(ss1:startswith('hello'))  -- true: correct
```

Just note that `"some string literal":startswith(str)` will not work: a string literal does not have `string` table functions as "methods". You have to use `tostring` or function rather than method:

```
print(tostring('goodbye hello'):startswith('hello')) -- false: correct
print(tostring('hello goodbye'):startswith('hello')) -- true: correct
print(string.startswith('hello goodbye', 'hello'))   -- true: correct
```

Problem with the last line is that syntax is a bit confusing: is it the first string that's the pattern, or second one? Also, the patter parameter ('hello' in the example) can be any valid pattern; if it already starts with `^` the result is a false negative, so to be robust the `startswith` method should only add the `^` anchor if it is not already there.

Comment: just a comment here: if you use functions like this self:find('^' .. str) or sub/gsub, match etc. you have to manually escape regex characters, otherwise wont work if you'll have special chars like /*.+ etc.

Comment: the problem with find is that you need to escape the regex special chars in `str`.

Answer (score 5):

There are probably a number of different ways to solve this, here's one.

```
userInput = ... -- however you're getting your cleaned and safe string
firstWord = userInput:match("^(%S+)")
-- validate firstWord
```

You might want to write your own statement parser where you process the string into known tokens, etc.